# Проблема с чередующимися изображениями. Отсутствие первого изображения

Tags: javascript

Есть список изображений:

```
<img src="/images/fon/70.jpg" id="img_0" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/50.jpg" id="img_1" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/49.jpg" id="img_2" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/55.jpg" id="img_3" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/56.jpg" id="img_4" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/77.jpg" id="img_5" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/88.jpg" id="img_6" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
```

И код смены изображений:

```
var image_count = 6;
var interval = 16000;
var time_out = 5;
var i = getRandomInt(0, 7);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var timeout;
var opacity = 100;
var current_image2 = 'img_' + i;

function change_image() {
    opacity--;
    var j = i + 1;
    var current_image = 'img_' + i;
    if (i == image_count) j = 0;
    var next_image = 'img_' + j;
    document.getElementById(current_image).style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    document.getElementById(current_image).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')';
    document.getElementById(next_image).style.opacity = (100 - opacity) / 100;
    document.getElementById(next_image).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (100 - opacity) + ')';
    timeout = setTimeout('change_image()', time_out);
    if (opacity == 1) {
        opacity = 100;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    if (i > image_count) i = 1;
    change_image();
}, interval);
```

Но первое изображение появляется лишь через определённое время. И вместо изображения (до смены) пустое место. Как поместить туда изображение сразу? То есть, как Вы видите, есть переменная `i` и она определяется рандомно. Поэтому первое изображение должно ориентироваться на неё, а далее по очереди в списке изображение меняется.

Answer (score 0):

```
function startImageRotation() {

  function timerProc() {
    i++; 
    if (i>image_count) 
      i=1; 
    change_image();
  }

  timerProc();

  setInterval (timerProc, interval);
}

startImageRotation();
```

*Update*

Уберите из кода строчки

```
timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", time_out);
```

и

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Я затрудняюсь понять, зачем они нужны.

Comment: все вроде работает, но после появления этой первой картинки она тут же сменяется.. можно создать паузу? Т.е. ту же паузу, что длится между сменами картинок и прописана в коде

Comment: @user250973 смотрите *Update* в ответе

Comment: Да, всё замечательно, но есть ещё один последний момент. Эта первая картинка - она появляется плавно меняя прозрачность. А нельзя чтобы она сразу была? Т.е. чтобы при загрузке страницы картинка уже была на месте без появления (именно первая), а далее уже пошло как надо?